# Strange and rare DB related exception

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, exception, c3p0

A few days before I got a very strange exception that someone couldn't log in to my application. Now I'm to reproduce it...

Here is the exception:

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:428)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:372)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:417)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:255)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82....
    ....at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1387)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:62)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:71)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:378) ... 87 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: JDBC begin transaction failed:
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1392)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.begin(TransactionImpl.java:59) ... 89 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 32,971,422 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3559)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4110)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2809)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:5333)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.setAutoCommit(NewProxyConnection.java:912)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:72) ... 92 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3570) ... 100 more
```

I got only once so far, and have no idea how to reproduce. Another thousands of log in were successfully. If I'm not mistaken, the root cause is a kind of timeout on database side - I don't know what, just an intuition... Therefore extended the report with the last request time and the time when the server generates the report, but nothing has happened since.

Any suggestion what is it or how to reproduce?

Comment: `Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 32,971,422 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.` This seems to be a network error.

Comment: in my experience when working with jpa, everything is strange and rare

Comment: The DB can be found on same server (localhost), so I'm not sure if this was a network failure

Comment: Do you use a connection pool ? Could be that one session has been usused, waiting in the pool for a long time - 32,971 seconds, then it has been retireved from the pool, but MySql has already closed this connection because `wait_timeout` (or `interactive_timeout`) has expired.

Comment: Yes, I use
`<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.7.Final</version>
</dependency>`

Comment: Got it again, but couldn't reproduce according to the user's guide. Btw, I also have found on the internet that it could be a timeout on MySql side and the following config may fix it:
- hibernate.c3p0.testOnBorrow=true
- hibernate.c3p0.testOnReturn=true
- hibernate.c3p0.testWhileIdle=true
- hibernate.c3p0.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
- hibernate.c3p0.numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
- hibernate.c3p0.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000

Comment: Oh, and hibernate.c3p0.validationQuery=SELECT 1

Comment: @BenjaminSzabo I know this is a pretty old post but do you remember if it worked? I got the same issue now.